# Is it possible to use MongoDB $lookup to join two aggregation pipeline results after $facet?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to use MongoDB $lookup to join two aggregation pipeline results with $facet ?

Let's say I have two aggregation outputs as shown :

```
{
"pipe1" : [{"_id": 1, "count":3}, {"_id": 2, "count":2}, ... ],
"pipe2" : [{"_id": 1, "sum":6}, {"_id": 2, "sum":8}, ... ]
}
```

I want to join them to something like

```
[{"_id": 1, "count":3, "sum": 6}, {"_id": 2, "count":3, "sum": 8}, ... ]
```

Comment: Use `$group` instead with `_id` as null in the group stage

Comment: You again ! :) Can you explain a bit more ? I added examples to my question

Comment: Hi, added an answer. See if it works. Let me know if you need even more explanation. Also, don't hesitate to ask for more queries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unwind both the arrays first and then proceed with the group pipeline.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$pipe1",
          "$pipe2",
          
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$newRoot"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$newRoot._id",
      "sum": {
        "$sum": "$newRoot.sum"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": "$newRoot.count"
      },
    },
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0-dXnvI-897)

Comment: thanks for the doule unwind method ! The problem is that i dont have any _id field, just pipe1 and pipe2. I did a match $eq pipe1._id & pipe2._id, but this way I can only achieve a inner join..

Comment: @NoaBe I got it now. I have updated the answer. See if this works out for you. Note: The above solution might not work in cases where the previous stage is not `$facet`. But it will for sure work if implemented after `$facet` stage.